# How to get an object by identifier?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, storyboard

I feel this should be simple but I can't find an answer. I want to get a reference to a navigation controller (or any object/view, actually) using an identifier I assigned it in storyboard (in this case "myNavCon"). I want something like this to work:

```
UINavigationController *myNavigationController = [self getObjectByIdentifier:@"myNavCon"];
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this by assigning the navigation controller to an app delegate property (where it can be referenced globally) from an early view that contained only the 1 navigation controller.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to use `- (id)instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier` from the UIStoryboard class. More info here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStoryboard_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: I'm confused about this method...isn't my navcontroller already instantiated? I just want to get a reference to it, not instantiate it again.

Comment: Why not just use self.navigationController?

Comment: Because I have 2 navigation controllers in the same view...self.navigationController only returns one of them. I need a reference to the other one.

Comment: Then use an IBOutlet and create a reference to it. On a separate note, two navigation controllers in the same view sounds like a problem in itself!

Comment: Solved this using an app delegate property. See my answer above.